# last td of table with if statement - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are lots of answers about this but none of them includes any `if` statement. So, I need something like this:

```
if($(this) == "last <td> of the row")
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You mean `:last`? Like `if ($(this).is('td:last'))`

Comment: @fuyushimoya it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry messed up with `:last` and `:last-child`, posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector to test if its the last child of its parents.

From jQuery API Doc:

> :last-child
>
> - SelectorSelects all elements that are the last child of their parent.
> - While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more    than one: one for each parent.

So if you use `td:last`, you'll only get true when click on `8` in the snippet(and if you don't use `td:last` but `:last`, no td will tested true as they're all not the last element in the DOM)

While click on `4` and `8` will both tested true if you use `:last-child`, as they both are the last `td` in `tr`.

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
    console.log('last');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```